# window.focus doesn't work within http promise then

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I try to make a `focus` on a new tab window , within callback (`then` function) of a `http` request and it doesn't work . i.e -

```
$http.get('').then(function () {
    that.myWin.focus(); // isn't focusing 
})
```

I did a **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/urielz/tv53z0nt/2/)** for that , press "Open" to open the tab and then press "Focus" to focus in this tab which doesn't work .

Here is another [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/urielz/tv53z0nt/3/) which isn't within `then` that works fine .

How to make the `focus` function to work well ?

---

#### EDIT :

I'm testing on **Google Chrome**.

Comment: neither of your demos focus the new tab when pressing focus

Comment: works for me , probably it depends on browser .

Comment: are you getting any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: nope , I also added the `log` to make sure I getting in the callback

Comment: First demo doesn't work, the second works. Interesting question :)

Comment: which browser allows you to change the current tab like that? Firefox definitely does not

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of wiered issue, on which spent my couple of hours and actually I found something working.

While debugging I found that if, we tries to focus tab for than `1 sec` of time, It doesn't focus the tab. So I assumed that in one second I should access `that.myWin` object, otherwise after `1sec` nothing happens with tab focusing.

```
$scope.focus = function() {
    //maintained flag for checking promise completed or not.
    var promiseResolved = false; //by default false
    // on each second I'm checking promise has resolved or not.
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (promiseResolved) {
        console.log('Going to focus tab')
        clearInterval(interval); //clearing interval
        that.myWin.focus(); //focusing tab
      }
    }, 1000); // 1sec interval because of above assumption
    //ajax call using $http
    $http.get('').then(function() {
      //set flag to true when promise resolved
      promiseResolved = true;
      console.log("I'm here");
    });
};
```

I know I partially figured out what may be happening, but anyone can point out, if they find anything right/wrong in my answer. I'd appreciate that help. Thanks.

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pankajparkar/k34ek9he/)